# How to protect a WCF service method with specific windows identity

Tags: wcf, security

I have a WCFservice named IEnvironmentService. This service provides some unsecure methods. I have to protect some methods in this service. In order to protect this methods I want to use windows identity. So other than the specific windows identity service methods cannot be callable. How can I achieve this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your service implementation (you can't do anything about this on contract):

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"DOMAIN\group")]
public void DoSomethingInsecure()
{
    // do stuff
}
```